# Are military and passenger jets insured?

Tags: insurance

Are aircrafts insured? Basically, I want to ask who bears the financial liability in case of some mishap? The airline company/government or some other company.

Comment: 1. Passengers - yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_insurance for more info.

2. Military (unsure hence non answer) - Very unlikely, would be very high premiums and would usually be cheaper not too.

In terms of liability, it depends what the mishap was. In most cases the insurers would cover the costs, but the liability may remain solely on the pilot.

Comment: okay.. but even then premiums would be very high for some aircraft like an a380, also which pilot would be so rich to take the liability of whole aircraft?

Comment: It would, however most airliners get fleet insurance, to cover all of their fleet. which reduces the cost. I also believe that commercial flights in planes such as an a380 must be insured.

Comment: I believe that ICAO rules mandate liability coverage on all civil aircraft. In fact, it is often the insurance company that poses the strictest conditions for the operation (stricter than the national aviation authority), for instance on crew training and experience levels required to operate the aircraft. And since the insurance is mandatory, if you can't fulfil their requirements, the plane can't fly (legally).

Comment: I'd be surprised if military combat aircraft are insured for damage or hull-loss. I doubt any insurer would insure combat missions. Large organisations can often self-insure (i.e. they have sufficient income to cover routine losses) and the military can almost always get additional one-off funding from governments for replacement costs during periods of high loss-rates (i.e. combat attrition).

Comment: In insurance industry, this is not the aircraft which is insured, but the person at the origin of the damage in which the aircraft is *involved*. The damage may be to the aircraft, to the crew, to the passengers, to other assets, to other persons, etc, and the insurance may cover the repair and/or the liabilities/damages for others. Application example: who is liable for an a eardrum perforation to a passenger traveling without a valid ticket ? Will an insurance cover this damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commercial aircraft are insured in exactly the same way that companies insure other vehicles like cars. Broadly speaking, a company - the airline in this case - purchases hull insurance and liability insurance. The hull insurance covers damage to the aircraft and the liability insurance covers other costs like damage to property, medical payments, compensation to passengers and other costs caused by an event. [Lloyd's of London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_of_London) has a [useful summary](http://www.lloyds.com/Redirect-pages/Risk_locator/Aircraft_hull_and_liability_and_aviation_liability_insurance). There are also all sorts of specialized insurance policies available to cover specific flights, aircraft, countries, cargoes etc.

Small private aircraft can be insured in the same way, although many owners of older, less valuable aircraft don't buy hull insurance because over a period of years the premiums can be more than the value of the aircraft. Most pilots do carry liability insurance, however, to cover medical or other expenses for themselves and their passengers (although in the US at least there's no requirement for pilots to have any insurance at all).

I don't know anything about military aircraft and it's a more complicated case: governments are [typically immune from liability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_immunity) (at least, you can't sue them) so it really depends on the legal situation and practices in each country.

Comment: ya, you cant sue govt but the govt must have paid for the  aircraft, what about that money? Nice answer for passenger though!

Comment: You mean to cover the hull loss of govt aircraft? That money is usually called fiscal budget. And it comes from our tax money :)

Comment: As long as the government can tax its citizens, it will have no problem replacing a lost jet.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer for the case of military peacetime accidents: the government concerned seems to take responsibility for compensation - a few examples:

- [Cavalese cable car disaster (1998)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalese_cable_car_disaster_(1998))
- [2012 Virginia Beach F/A-18 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Virginia_Beach_F/A-18_crash)